# All new calls to cloud translation service are ending in quota error

Tags: google-translate, google-translation-api

Yesterday, about 1500 PST, my connection to the translation API began emitting errors about exceeding:

Error 8: RESOURCE EXHAUSTED: Quota Error

Quota exceeded for quota metric ‘v2 and v3 general model characters’ and limit ‘v2 and v3 general model characters per day’.

I have googled online, and found this can happen, and that it resets at 0000 hours PST.  This time has come and gone, and second day now, the same Error 8 is arriving when attempting to access the service.

I have also signed in to my console, and looked at my quotas.  None of them are over-quota, or have they been in the last 7 days.  (I’m no where near the limits)

I had a spike (bug) where the code got into a bad state and spammed the API retrying the request, and I’ve found an fixed this issue.  This was yesterday, so I don’t know why it’s still giving errors.

Answer (score 2):

OK so I found the answer.  My credit card had expired, and the billing was overdue.  Unfortunately this is not obvious in any of the errors, or many of the pages the google search results point to (check quotas etc)…hopefully this helps someone else who searches.